# On page script not executing with Salesforce Web-To-Lead code.

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, salesforce

This form works when the form action is "submit". However, upon customizing it to a Salesforce Web-to-Lead, the script that says "The form submission was successful" doesn't appear.

Additionally, the code in here to redirect the site after submission doesn't work. I'm no a PHP/Java expert and I don't really know what's happening enough to understand why it isn't working.

See below. Redacted private info from Salesforce.

```
<div class="padpage padtop">
    <h1>Let Us Call You</h1>
</div>
<!--end padpage-->

<div class="cutContainer moreUpperMargin">
    <span class="cutTop"></span>
    <span class="cutBottom"></span>

    <div class="ui-widget successMessage">
        <div class="ui-state-highlight ui-corner-all">
            <p><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-info" style=""></span>
            <strong>Success!</strong> Your mail has been sent.</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <h4> Write to us </h4>

    <form action="https://www.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.WebToLead?encoding=UTF-8" method="POST" />
        <input type=hidden name="oid" value="000000000000000">
        <input type=hidden name="retURL" value="http://www.xxxxxxxx.com">
        <input type=hidden name="company" value="Mobile Lead">

        <!-- A bunch of Fields.... -->


        <input type="submit"  class="button buttonStrong right" value="Send"          name="buttonSubmit" value="submit">  
        <div class="clearfix"></div>  
    </form>        

</div>
<!--end cut container-->
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you be more clear about the issue? If you want to use Salesforce standard functionality and presumably not program any custom PHP / Javascript, why don't you create another web page that includes the message, "The form submission was successful", and direct the user to that page through the retURL field upon submission?

Or, if you are using a popular CMS, try one of the plugins. Good ones exist for Wordpress and Drupal.

http://wordpress.org/plugins/salesforce-wordpress-to-lead/
https://drupal.org/project/sfweb2lead_webform

stony